# Replace isset for each $_POST using foreach

Tags: php

I've been trying to replace each isset for $_POST(s) using foreach.

This is the real code using isset for each $_POST :

```
<form method='post'>

    <input type='text' name='name'> <br>
    <input type='text' name='address'> <br>
    <input type='submit' name='send'> 

</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['address']) && isset($_POST['send']))
{
   echo "All elements have been submitted";
}
   else
{
   echo "You forget some elements, try checking name or address";
}

?>
```

is there a way I can replace 4 isset(s) above with single isset using for each?
I've made this and it goes wrong.

```
<form method='post'>

    <input type='text' name='nama'> <br>
    <input type='text' name='alamat'> <br>
    <input type='submit' name='kirim'> 

</form>

<?php

foreach($_POST as $value)
{
    if (isset($value))
    {
      echo "All elements have been submitted";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "You forget some elements, try checking name or address";
    }
}
?>
```

Need help guys, It's just wasting of time if I have to write isset one by one for each element I send via post / get. I've seen something like this before in visual basic, my friend made an foreach construct to validate all textboxes in a form, so he didn't need to create something like this anymore :

```
if textbox1.text="" && textbox.2.text="" and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** jbrahy just had a typo.  His answer is good now.

I think jbrahy's approach is the right general idea... but I don't think it actually works.

I'd do this.

```
    $requiredFields = ["nama","alamat","kirim"];

    $allElementsSet = true;
    foreach ($requiredFields as $requiredField)
    {
         if (!isset($_POST[$requiredField]))
         {
             $allElementsSet = false;
             break;
         }
    }
    if ($allElementsSet)
    {
        echo "All elements have been submitted";
    } else {
        echo "You forget some elements, try checking name or address";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

$_POST will only have the variables that are passed in and there are HTML elements that might not be passed in by just submitting. It's probably best to create a $required_fields array and even better if you can get some field validation but that's not what you asked for here. You'll want to take the key and value of $_POST.

```
$required_fields = array("name" => FALSE, "alamat" => FALSE, "kirim" => FALSE);

foreach ($required_fields as $key => $value){
    if (isset($_POST[$key])){
        $required_fields[$key] = TRUE;
    }
}

foreach ($required_fields as $key => $value){
     if (!$required_fields[$key]){
         echo "Missing value for " . $key;
     }
}
```

if you are trying to figure out if every key that is passed in has a value then something like this would work also.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    if ($value == ""){
        echo "Value(s) are missing";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just got an idea. Can I fully replace isset with required attribute in HTML5 form?

Anyway, Thanks before. I'm working with code you wrote, trying to understand it first :)

Comment: sure, but probably best accomplished using jquery's attr. Ask another question and I'll post and example. It doesn't really belong in this one.

Comment: I don't understand the line `if (isset($required_fields)){`... it will ALWAYS return `true` in this example unless I am missing something.

Comment: Thanks Evan, you were right. I had two arrays mixed. fixed now.